# How to implement a controller similar to Facebook's Android / iPhone app? (detailed)

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, controller

I am trying to find out which controller Facebook (among other apps. such as Wunderlist) is using.

The controller, or at least it's effect, looks like this:
[image: Controller explained]

If this is not a standard or public controller, can someone please explain how to develop one?
I am interested in the Android activity Layout and code that would accomplish this or some other options to make this smooth slider in Android. The same for iOS, which view hierarchy accomplishes this sliding motion smoothly.

To sum it up: how do I develop a view hierarchy that has an initial full screen view with a toolbar on top with 2 buttons (on toolbar's left and right side), and that upon button click, smoothly expands a side panel on the left or right side, scrolling the initial view almost completely out of sight except for the button used to toggle the side view. What xml/description to use and/or what code? Thanks.

Comment: I am interested in the iOS side as well, so that answer only helps me to get half there.

Comment: Well, someone who specializes in iOS could answer that for you. I marked as it duplicate considering the `Android` tag. Sorry to flag it, but for Android, that is a duplicate. :-(

Comment: Mostly for the sake of curiosity (_on my part_ ;-) ), a Google search gave these: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/saslidemenu, https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/iiviewdeckcontroller, https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu. They could be helpful. No clue about their validity though. I don't work on the iOS platform. Hopefully helpful. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Check this library project](https://github.com/korovyansk/android-fb-like-slideout-navigation).

You can easy built it into your application, your UI and navigation. You will need to implement only one Activity and one Fragment.Try it yourself also there is video available.

[Short video with record of demo project](http://youtu.be/Cqu7YdNMzeQ).

I hope it will help you.